# Как добавить строку в таблицу с помощтю AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

В данный момент я изучаю технологию `AJAX` и возникла трудность. Я хочу, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку у меня добавлялась строка в таблице, но не совсем понимаю как. Он добавляет запись в БД, но не обновляет таблицу, либо он полностью перезагружает страницу, либо надо самому её обновлять. 
`AJAX` код представлен ниже. 
Прошу сильно не критиковать, я новичок и учусь не покладая рук :3
Заранее спасибо

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'add_user.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    "log": log,
    "pas": pas
  },
  success: function(respond, status, jqXHR) {
    if (typeof respond.error === 'undefined') {
      // var html = '';
      $.each(respond.files, function(key, val) {
        $('tr.').prop('val', val);
        var html = "<tr><td class='edit_log' name='login' id='login'>log</td><td class='edit_pas' name='pas' id='pas'></td></tr>";
        location.reload();
      })
    }
    // error
    else {
      console.log('ОШИБКА: ' + respond.error);
    }

  },
  error: function() {
    console.log('ОШИБКА AJAX запроса: ');
  }
});
```

Comment: как связан ajax и работа с dom - правильно, никак.
как добавить html элемент - https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?alwaysStrict=false&allowUnusedLabels=true&ssl=11&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYSwTgzgLgXABAbwLACg7rgYwPYDtpwBG2AJgJ7wASAKgLIAyAogDYCmAtq7lHALxwlsmAK6duAOmLkA3KgxFSZcSHyswUAIIkAVgENMXKDQYAKAOSFWwbGFZcSZgDRwABgB4SIAG4A+T17cAen8fFwBKVABfVFQIVhxcEnhkNAwEgikKOGMmNjEefkERfMlFWVT0dJ5-KjpcjkM+ASFRQ3FMW10oVhYG7nN-MwiKgW9lXFw1HKazQbkMTPFdAAdl+wBhAAsQZhITf2HIoA

Answer (score 0):

Не понимаю зачем тебе each и ты сам делаешь релод.
В success, после проверки на ошибки просто добавь в конец таблицы html код который тебе нужен. Если это только одна строка, ты можешь html код сформировать на сервере и вернуть сразу готовую строку. А дальше в success добавляй ее в таблицу

```
 $(".table").append(html);
```

Comment: Смотри, когда я сам делаю reload, он полностью всю страницу перезагружает, в этом и заключается по сути главная проблема

Comment: Так он и должен перезагружать всю страну;)) Убери релоад совсем. Он тебе вообще не нужен. И если делаешь отправку из form. То отмени действие формы по умолчанию. Ну или сделай а конце, после ajax return false;